# for some reason music is not playing in the iphone sumulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, avaudioplayer

so I have the code shown but my music is not playing and I'm not sure why. the sound on my computer is turned up xcode can play the file that i imported in.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"starting Music");
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"rainbowRoad" withExtension:@"m4a"];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"awesome");
}
```

Comment: We need more info.  Can you NSLog `error`?

Comment: nope the only thing is the console are the NSLogs

Comment: Is `backgroundMusicURL` nil?

Comment: Why aren't you logging `error`? Have you debugged this code? Is `backgroundMusicURL` non-nil?

Comment: the error logs as null

Comment: backgroundMusicURL is nil the file that im trying to read is name rainbowRoad.m4a

Comment: @user3431724 In Xcode's File Inspector's Target Membership section, is your target checked?

Comment: "backgroundMusicURL is nil". I can't believe you just actually typed that sentence and at the same time had typed one saying "for some reason music is not playing".

Comment: As @NobodyNada suggested, your sound file is probably not being copied to your bundle. Check it's being copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your sound file is being copied.  Select your audio file in Xcode, then in the File Inspector's Target Membership section, make sure your target is checked.

[image: Check this thing!]